# Facebook send to messenger renders in html but button not shown

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger

My Facebook "send to messenger" button is not showing in browser, i have almost tried all the solutions given in stackoverflow.

My app is in development mode, page is added, webhook added and verified.

Below is my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
<title>My Website</title>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '1234567890',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v9.0'
    });
  };
</script>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
      fbmessegner button starts here 
      <div class="fb-send-to-messenger" messenger_app_id="1234567890" page_id="0987654321" data-ref="testingmessenger<?php echo time(); ?>" color="blue" size="large"> </div>
      ends here
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When i inspect elements i can see the script has loaded but its not showing, see below screenshot:

[image]

My browser screenshot :

[image]

Kindly advise

-Vijay

Comment: Did you whitelist your domain as well?

Comment: Yes i have whitelisted as well